# can't set password

Tags: sudo, password

I've just installed Ubuntu on my laptop and I'm trying to create sudo account
I ran 
sudo passwd root
and the system suggests me typing a password but i somehow can't. Neither letters nor figures appeare on a screen. Is it a bug or I did something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! No, it's not a bug, it's meant this way for security reasons. No characters appears on screen, just type your password and press Enter, if the password is correct, will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's the inherent security feature of Linux. However, if you want to see the asterisks as you type a password, follow this:

1. Open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```
2. Scroll down the list until you find the line:

   ```
   Defaults        env_reset
   ```
3. Append the word `pwfeedback` to the end of the line so it looks like:

   ```
   Defaults        env_reset,pwfeedback
   ```
4. Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).